# How to use a sparse matrix in numpy.linalg.solve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to solve the following linear system for `x`

```
Ax = b
```

Where A is sparse and b is just regular column matrix. However when I plug into the usual `np.linalg.solve(A,b)` routine it gives me an error. However when I do `np.linalg.solve(A.todense(),b)` it works fine.

### Question.

How can I use this linear solve still preserving the `sparseness` of `A`?. The reason is `A` is quite large about `150 x 150` and there are about 50 such matrices and so keeping it sparse for as long as possible is the way I'd prefer it.

I hope my question makes sense. How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: Can you add the error in the question?

Comment: if you are using sparse matrices, look for scipy's sparse algorithms instead: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/sparse.linalg.html#module-scipy.sparse.linalg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) only works for array-like objects. For example it would work on a `np.ndarray` or `np.matrix` (Example from the numpy documentation):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3,1], [1,2]])
b = np.array([9,8])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
```

or

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([[3,1], [1,2]])
b = np.array([9,8])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
```

or on `A.todense()` where `A=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.matrix([[3,1], [1,2]]))` as this returns a `np.matrix` object.

To work with a sparse matrix, you have to use [`scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve) (as already pointed out by rakesh)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg

a = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.matrix([[3,1], [1,2]]))
b = np.array([9,8])
x = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(a, b)
```

Note that `x` is still a `np.ndarray` and not a sparse matrix. A sparse matrix will only be returned if you solve Ax=b, with b being a matrix and not a vector.

Answer (score 4):

Use scipy instead to work on sparse matrices.You can do that using `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`. For further details read its documentation [spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve)