# scipy matrix solver error: nzvals is not of a type supported by SuperLU

Tags: scipy, python-3.7

I'm trying to use the script from an [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156532/python-baseline-correction-library) that uses `scipy` matrix solver to fit a baseline to some spectral data, by solving a matrix equation of the type: `Ax=b`.

Here's a section of my input array

```
    y = numpy.asarray([0.3227648437023163, 0.3186240792274475, 0.31572669744491577,
                       0.3266492336988449, 0.31392455101013184, 0.31541168689727783,
                       0.3163585960865021, 0.3191247135400772, 0.3223631978034973],
                      dtype=float)
```

and the posted script (the accepted answer)

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import sparse
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve

    def baseline_als(y, lam, p, niter=10):
      L = len(y)
      D = sparse.csc_matrix(np.diff(np.eye(L), 2))
      w = np.ones(L)
      for i in xrange(niter):
        W = sparse.spdiags(w, 0, L, L)
        Z = W + lam * D.dot(D.transpose())
        z = spsolve(Z, w*y)
        w = p * (y > z) + (1-p) * (y < z)
      return z

    bl = baseline_als(y, lam=1e05, p=.01, niter=10)
```

that reproduce the following error message:

```
File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py", line 196, in spsolve
    b, flag, options=options)
TypeError: nzvals is not of a type supported by SuperLU
```

pointing to the line `z = spsolve(Z, w*y)` of this code.

(As a side note, I followed the recommendation for parameters' values in the linked answer:

> We found that generally 0.001 ≤ p ≤ 0.1 is a good choice (for a signal with positive peaks) and 10^2 ≤ λ ≤ 10^9, but exceptions may occur.>

with meaningful mid-range values of p=0.01, and lambda =1e05.)

However, when a random vector is supplied:

```
    y = numpy.random.randn(1000)
```

the function produced some real output, without any error messages.

1. I looked at `linsolve.py`'s line 196 but couldn't deduce how to proceed as my vector `w*y` is correctly shaped as an `ndarray` of shape `(n,)` or `(n,1)` as stated in the `linsolve.py`'s comment section (where it is referred to as a vector `b`).
2. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528238/how-to-use-a-sparse-matrix-in-numpy-linalg-solve), and in the `linsolve.py`'s comment section, changing `b` to `b.todense()` didn't help. Also, my web search didn't return any hits related to this error message.

Since the error message refers to the data type running the `type` command on both, my data and the random vector, produced the expected result:

```
    (9,), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    (1000,), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I'm utterly confused about how to troubleshoot this error. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

System: OSX 10.15.4, numpy 1.18.3, scipy 1.4.1.

Comment: I would test `Z` and `w*y` at each iteration till you find the combination that raises the error.  DImensions are small enough.  With a test case (guessing a function argument values) it runs for me.

Comment: I tested it and got the error immediately (at the first iteration).

Comment: the i must have guessed wrong about lam and p.

Comment: I clarified the question to include the recommended values for lam and p in the function call.

Comment: How about `dtype`?

Comment: ```numpy.dtype(y)``` gave me ```TypeError: data type not understood```, which is not what I expected since I defined ```y``` (above) by specifying ```dtype``` argument as ```float```.

Comment: After one week of trying to deal with this issue I am no longer able to reproduce it and I can't point to a reliable root cause at this moment. I might have set the python environment incorrectly because I have 3.7 and 3.8 versions of python installed on my machine but I can't surmise how that might relate to this issue.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution so I used similar function shown in the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57431514/4408539)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced just the very same issue and I was able to solve it by changing the line:

```
z = spsolve(Z, w*y)
```

**with:**

```
z = spsolve(Z, w*y.astype(np.float64))
```

According to the section **"New Function"** in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350711/baseline-correction-for-spectroscopic-data).